# Why insert JPA null in Database

Tags: java, jpa, websphere

I have a table with a last modification date. I want to set this manually in my program. Strangely, JPA reads the object correctly and the date is present, so a column error is actually not possible. However, when I create a new object now, an error message appears that JPA cannot write NULL to the LastChange Date field.(Before persist() of the EntityManager I checked if the date is NULL and it exists)
I use WAS 9.0 and the Default Eclipselink with JPA 2.1

---

Here in my Testfall class:

```
@Column(Name="LetztesAenderungsdatum",insertable=true,updateable=true)
private java.sql.Date letztesAenderungsdatum
```

---

table Schema

```
    CREATE TABLE Test
    (
        Testfall_Id             INT (7),
        LetztesAenderungsdatum  DATE NOT NULL,
        Name                    VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
        Verfahren_FK    INT CONSTRAINT Verfahren_FK REFERENCES 
        Verfahren(VERFAHREN_ID),
        CONSTRAINT testfall_Id PRIMARY KEY(Testfall_Id)
    );
```

---

before Stack trace a Sysout with date:
[12.06.18 13:45:14:415 CEST] 0000009f SystemOut   O Testfall letztes Aenderungsdatum: 2018-06-12

---

stack trace:

```
    [12.06.18 13:45:25:289 CEST] 0000009f eclipselink   W   [eclipselink] Ausnahme [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.WAS-v20170717-04d37b5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Interne Ausnahme: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: Einfügen von NULL in ("SCHEMA"."TESTFALL"."LETZTESAENDERUNGSDATUM") nicht möglich

Fehlercode: 1400
Aufruf: INSERT INTO SCHEMA.Testfall (Testfall_Id, Beschreibung, LetztesAenderungsdatum, Name, Verfahren_FK) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [5 parameters bound]
Abfrage: InsertObjectQuery(myPackage.beans.Testfall@bcd7e11c)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the date **before** calling `persist`. You can also include `nullable = false` in your annotation mapping.

what you probably wanna do is something like this:

```
@PreUpdate
protected void onUpdate() {
    letztesAenderungsdatum = new Date();
}

@PrePersist
protected void onPersist() {
    letztesAenderungsdatum = new Date();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This saves me code, but I still get the same error message. I've also tried nullable = false, but it doesn't work. Then I still get the same error message.

Comment: ` public void speichere(Testfall testfall) {
  System.out.println("Testfall hat das Aenderungsdatum: "+testfall.getLetztesAenderungsdatum());
  beginneTransaktion();
  if(pruefeNeu(testfall)){
   this.getManager().persist(testfall);
  }
  else{
   this.getManager().merge(testfall);
  }
   beendeTransaktion();
  if(this.getManager().contains(testfall)){
   this.getManager().refresh(testfall);
  }
  else{
   System.out.println("Testfall wurde nicht gespeichert");
  }
 }`

Comment: When you call `this.getManager().persist(testfall);`, is the date null at this moment? With the code above, it is basically guaranteed that date will never be null. Which entity provider are you using? EclipseLink? Hibernate? Did you create the schema yourself or was it generated?

Comment: When I call the persist() method, the Date object exists. The output is above the stack trace. That shouldn't be a problem. I have already written which provider I use. I use the standard EclipseLink provider of WAS 9. Although now I get zero, because I use the annotation PrePersist and set the date there.  @PreUpdate
 `protected void onUpdate(){
  letztesAenderungsdatum = new Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());
 }
 @PrePersist
 protected void onPersist(){
  letztesAenderungsdatum = new Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());
 }`

Comment: ok, it works now. There was another bug in my Project. Thank you!

Comment: Great! I was trying to figure out what could be wrong. Please upvote/accept my answer then, ok? Thanks.